# The Who/Whom examples in Strunk and White's Elements of Grammar

Tags: grammar, ambiguity, whom, who

From Strunk & White, Elements of Grammar, 3rd Ed., p.11: "When *who* introduces a subordinate clause, its case depends on its function in that clause."    They then give four examples without explaining which, if any, is incorrect.  They give no further comment on the four examples which are:

1. "Virgil Soames is the candidate whom we think will win."
2. "Virgil Soames is the candidate who we think will win."
3. "Virgil Soames is the candidate whom we hope to elect."
4. "Virgil Soames is the candidate who we hope to elect."

It seems to me that 2 and 3 are correct (since we think *he* will win, and we hope to elect *him*).   Is this what Strunk and White are driving at, or am I missing something more complicated?

Specifically I would like to reconcile number 2 with an explanation in A Grammar Book for You and I ... Ooops Me by C. Edward Good.   It says (p.138) to use *whom* for a clause that already has a subject.  It looks to me like number 2 above has a subject, *we*, and should therefore, according to Good, take *whom* as the relative pronoun.   Which is correct, Good or S&W?

Comment: Please search for previous answers. S & W is not considered a reliable authority on this issue by most regular members here. 'Who' (and often 'that' or _zero relative_) have largely replaced 'whom'.

Comment: I know the older question is not an exact duplicate; but in its essence, the OP is asking "how" the pronouns, *who* and *whom*, should be used.

Comment: There are already more than 60 questions and answers [tagged with 'whom'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whom?sort=votes). Which of those have you read?

Answer (score 1):

You've got it right. When in doubt, try substituting "her" and "she," and, depending on which one fits, use "whom" (for "her") and "who" (for "she").

Comment: In this case, the purportedly more sexist "he" and "him" actually makes sound mnemonic sense, as "whom/him" and "who/he" are much easier pairs to associate than "whom/her" and "who/she".

Comment: @Hellion: Sometimes you need to get away from mnemonics and allow the contrast to do the job.